# Batch file not able to run after upgrade to window10

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which worked well in window 7. After got new computer with window 10, the batch file will not able to run anymore. 
What happens is if I right click on the batch file and Run as administration and Window command just launch and disappear (Batch file not able to run).

Please help and thank you.

I have them like this:

```
@echo off 
REM (c) 2015 
CLS 
TITLE file finder 
REM finds files in list.txt file and copies them to C:\copied REM CHECK FOR ADMIN RIGHTS 
COPY /b/y NUL %WINDIR%\06CF2EB6-94E6-4a60-91D8-AB945AE8CF38 >NUL 2>&1 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO:NONADMIN 
DEL %WINDIR%\06CF2EB6-94E6-4a60-91D8-AB945AE8CF38 >NUL 2>&1 
:ADMIN 
REM GOT ADMIN RIGHTS 
COLOR 1F 
ECHO Hi, %USERNAME%! 
ECHO Please wait... 
FOR /R "%~dp0" %%I IN (.) DO for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%~dp0list.txt") do echo d |xcopy "%%I\%%a" "C:\your_files" /s /i 
COLOR 2F 
ECHO. 
ECHO (c) Copying done PAUSE
GOTO:EOF 
:NONADMIN REM NO ADMIN RIGHTS 
COLOR 4F ECHO. 
ECHO PLEASE RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR 
ECHO. pause 
GOTO:EOF
```

Comment: What error do you get when you run the script from the command prompt instead of double-clicking it?

Comment: What happens if you start a command prompt and then execute the batch file from within it? You may be getting a useful error message, but the console window is closing too fast.

Comment: GUID directory names are likely to change between Windows versions, updates, machines and users. Are you sure the GUID's in your script are actually stable?